# Access Model in JS View to Render Programmatically

Tags: sapui5

I have a master/ detail use-case and I'm binding 
the selected Element like this:

```
  handleRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    var oParameters = oEvent.getParameter('name');
    if (oParameters !== 'visualization') return;
    var varPath = oEvent.getParameter('arguments').contextPath;
    this.getView().bindElement('/assets/'+ varPath);
  },
```

This basically works, the data is available to the view.
Now, however I want to access this data in the JS view to
make programmatic decisions about what is rendered.

The problem is that in neiher of the hooks I know `init()`,
`onBeforeShow(evt)`, `createContent()`, the data is available.
I debugged this and found that all these hooks are executed **before**
the binding is created so it's somewaht logical.

There must however be a way to be notified in a view once
the model is available or it has changed. This would solve my problem,
so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Binding the element only sets the binding context, but doesn't add any real model binding.

You could try to bind the content of the view to your model, which should enable the view to be updated when the model changes.

On a side note, if your view has to be created entirely different, depending on the model data, you might want to consider a different approach and use multiple views with less programmatic decisions.